# How is "Table per concrete class with unions" implemented using Hibernate Annotation/JPA?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

How is "Table per concrete class with unions" using Hibernate Annotation/JPA?
It is recommended by using

> The subclasses are mapped using the union-subclass element

But if we use

> @Entity 
>   @Inheritance (strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) public
>   class Disc_4{ .... }

is this a case of "Table per concrete class with implicit polymorphism" or "Table per concrete class with unions"?